# How to stop/pause async call of ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am stuck on this since yesterday, now I need help. I don't know how to properly 'question' this, but I think this is around the concern of ajax is asynchronous.

I am unable to complete the ajax call from my view when I call an ajax function inside an ajax postback.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("GetValidateAssignAccountName", "AccountsAssignment")?companyID=' + companyid,
  type: request_method,
  data: form_data
}).done(function (data) {
  if (data == '') {
    PromptAssign(data, post_url, request_method, form_data);
  }
  else {
    Assign(post_url, request_method, form_data);
  }
});
```

`Assign` function doesn't work/complete. I don't know how to call it, but it goes through the controller and calls the stored procedure, returns a success msg, but for some reason, the procedure did not work/save.

My problem is that, when I call `PromptAssign` - in which case I call a `messageDialog` and then call the `Assign` inside, right there the `Assign` does the job. Here is the `PromptAssign` function:

```
$("#messagedialog").dialog({
  open: function () {
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").css({ background: "#000000", opacity: 0.5 });
    $(".ui-dialog-title").css("color", "#228B22");
    //$(".message-img").attr("src", "../Content/images/success.png");
    $(".message-wrapper").html(msg);
  },
  modal: true, height: 250, width: 500,
  buttons: {
    //'Ok': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); },
    'Assign': function () {
      Assign(post_url, request_method, form_data);
      $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    'Close': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
  },
  create: function () {
    $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
      .find(".ui-button").eq(2)
      .addClass("btn btn-default");
  },
  title: "Confirmation",
  dialogClass: "noclose"
});
```

Initially, the code was just the assign function which calls an sp to save a data. But we added the `PromptAssign` (first code block, then call a msgbox/`PromptAssign`, then assign) which is a validation if its existing or not, then the user can still `Assign` after if he still chooses to.

So when the validation returns nothing, I don't need to `PromptAssign`, so I just call the `Assign` straight away. This is not working. Anything I am missing on how to use ajax?

Comment: I don’t think there is an issue with your AJAX call. Can you update your answer and share the code in your controller action and “Assign” method?

Comment: What does "does not work" means? Is Assign function called or not?

Comment: 1. When you click buttons: Assign then doesn't the Assign() function working well? Or 
2. When from  
else  {
    Assign(post_url, request_method, form_data);
  }
doesn't the Assign() function working well? 

3. From Both it is not working

Comment: You can set async: false when calling the ajax method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer the comments, there was an earlier problem like this that goes to the ajax, and then to the controller executing the stored procedure but for some reason the data isn't updated. We fixed the issue by making those ajax calls in a separate function.

For this one, I was trying to apply the same thing to no avail, I know there is nothing wrong in my way of using ajax, turns out, it was a data issue. The specific record in which I was testing is not working properly due to database validations. Still, thank you for looking at it.